# Display HTML file with image in QTextEdit

Tags: html, image, qt, qtextedit

I am trying to display an HTML file contening an image and a liste with flee in a QTextedit.
However, neither the image and the flee appear.
My code is the following:

```
QFile file(QString::fromUtf8(st.c_str()));
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
ui->textEdit->setHtml(file.readAll());
file.close();
```

The HTML document for image is thiw one:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <img src="/home/build-untitled-Desktop-Release/about/Versions_SOFT_files/image001.jpg">
    <p>paragraph which contains some text</p>
</html>
```

For the flee, I used a word file that I convert to html on windows.
Any idea of why image and flee does not appear?

Comment: 1. Check file name after convert `fromUtf8()`.
2. Check last file error `file.errorString()` after `file.open()`
3. Check supported image formats with `QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()`. Maybe image plugins did not load.

Comment: fleas are easy to miss

Comment: Use `QWebView` instead of `QTextEdit` if you need html. Or read Qt documentation about supported html subset for line edit.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers. QWebView is really heavy and i would like to avoid it. Is there a way to open and display a document with text, images, tables inside a QApplication ?

Comment: In my case if the image is loaded correctly: https://imgur.com/a/uuvzEBD

Comment: What is your code ?

Comment: @froz the same as your code, try a route that does not have "_", with a compact name, plus I used a .png instead of .jpg.

Comment: Well, for me, even with png and short path, it still does not work. Which version do you have and what include do you load?