# Images in QTextEdit - some are displayed, some not

Tags: python, html, image, pyqt, anaconda

I want to display a short manual in a tab of program
(Windows 10, anaconda distribution, python 3.7.6, pyqt 5.12).
I wrote a text document with html inside and load it in a QTextEdit using

```
self.te_short_manual = QTextEdit()  # Textedit for display
with open(os.path.join(py_file_folder, r"doc_files\tab5_documentation.html"), "r") as doc_file:
    lines = doc_file.readlines()
doc_text = "\n".join(lines)
self.te_short_manual.setHtml(doc_text)            
self.te_short_manual.setReadOnly(True)
```

In the text document I use the img command to load an image:

```
<p>
<img src="banana_select_roi_nb2.tif" alt="Safely selecting a ROI" width="500" >
<br>FIG 1: <i>How to use the color map limits to better define the ROI.</i>
</p>
```

Using this image [image_faisceau_  28.tif](https://www.fresnel.fr/perso/wagner/temp/so_question_2021/image_faisceau_%20%2028.tif), I see the image as wished (but not in Firefox).
Using this image [banana_select_roi_nb.tif](https://www.fresnel.fr/perso/wagner/temp/so_question_2021/banana_select_roi_nb.tif), I do not see the image (in Firefox neither).
Using this image [IR_0309.jpg](https://www.fresnel.fr/perso/wagner/temp/so_question_2021/IR_0309.jpg), I do not see the image (but I see it in Firefox).
All images and the text document are in the same directory.

I read about QWebView here
[Display HTML file with image in QTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829947/display-html-file-with-image-in-qtextedit), but would like to avoid it.

Running supportedImageFormats() shows a long list including tif, tiff, jpg, png, ... formats

https://forum.qt.io/topic/54924/solved-a-png-image-within-html-code-in-a-qtextedit
reported something similar with the image not showing in firefox when showing in QTextEdit,
but adding "html/" in the src-value did not help. There is still this kind of placeholder displayed... and anyway, one of the two tif-images works.

In addition to some help to solve the problem on my machine, comments on the expected robustness
off my apporach would be appreciated. I wonder what happens if I give the program to somebody else. Ideally I would like it to work on all standard Anaconda installs.

Comment: Note that your URLs go to a redirect page with instruction to download - perhaps how at a straight-forward URL?

Comment: Hello, as suggested I replaced the download links by straight forward URLs. Would be fine if someone could tell me the critical difference between the two tif files. First I thought it was the color, but even with the greyscale tif image (made by photoshop CS) it does not work. Best would be anyway if it worked with jpg images... Thanks for any feedback.